# A Beginner Puzzle

Tags: riddle, steganography

> For my first *puzzle* on **Stack** Exchange,
>
> I *thought* I'd **start** in the beginner range,
>
> *Feverishly* close to the **solution**
>
> *Though* beginners will **take** the revolution.
>
> You **aren't** a beginner, so you can't get it right
>
> Only a *starter* would see **the** light
>
> Never so **close**, puts you *in* a slumber
>
> Even *or* odd - **what's** the hidden number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see

> 51 by taking the first letters of each line

Clues: 
For my first puzzle on Stack Exchange,

> "First"

I thought I'd start in the beginner range,

> "Start"

Feverishly close to the solution
Though beginners will take the revolution.

> "beginners"

You aren't a beginner, so you can't get it right

> "beginner"

Only a starter would see the light

> "starter"

Never so close, puts you in a slumber
Even or odd - what's the hidden number?

> and in the title... "beginner"

Comment: This is the right number, but your explanation is a small bit off.

Comment: Yep, well done. Correct answer and good explanation.